# A questions on subdomains

Tags: reactjs, nginx

So I am working on my service architecture, and for ease, I want to have one frontend application that runs everything, from my discord bot dashboard accessed through helix.sinlessgamesllc.com to my website hosted at sinlessgamesllc.com. I am using SSL and Nginx to serve my application.

nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.sinlessgamesllc.com sinlessgamesllc.com.com;

  # Redirect all traffic to SSL
  rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
  listen 7443 ssl http2 default_server;

  # enables SSLv3/TLSv1, but not SSLv2 which is weak and should no longer be used.
  ssl_protocols SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


  server_name www.sinlessgamesllc.com sinlessgamesllc.com;

  ## Access and error logs.
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log info;

  ## Keep alive timeout set to a greater value for SSL/TLS.
  keepalive_timeout 75 75;

  ## See the keepalive_timeout directive in nginx.conf.
  ## Server certificate and key.
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/priv.key;
  ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/cloudflare.crt;

  ## Strict Transport Security header for enhanced security. See
  ## http://www.chromium.org/sts. I've set it to 2 hours; set it to
  ## whichever age you want.
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=7200";

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

now I am certain that this configuration may not be strong, My DNS is done through Cloudflare and I use kemp between for level 7 load balancing. My application is hosted through docker.

My problem is when accessing the subdomain, I get the main access instead of the proper page. I am not sure if I have the react-router-dom setup wrong or if my config for Nginx is incorrect.

Comment: I use react-router-dom to subdoimain my application. I use nginx to host it inside a docker container. now my issue to be precise is:

basically I have two websites in a single application. now when I go to access the website 1 I get website 1, how ever accessing website 2 I get website 1 instead.

Comment: OK, that seems like a backend server configuration issue. I don't think `react-router` is involved here since it only works client-side once the server has served up the correct code for the URL requested.

Comment: So my question this is where did I mess up my Nginx config, I mean it does work in development so I was decently confident it wasn't that.